# How to pass data to cloud function file in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am new to flutter and I have just created app that accepts payments from user using `flutter_stripe: ^2.1.0` plugin. The amount in cloud function file `index.js` is fixed but I want to pass the amount that is calculated dynamically. Here is my code.

```
Future<void> makePayment() async {
final url = Uri.parse(
    'https://us-central1-carwashapp-376b6.cloudfunctions.net/stripePayment');
final response =
    await http.get(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
paymentIntentData = json.decode(response.body);
await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
  paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
    paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData['paymentIntent'],
    applePay: true,
    googlePay: true,
    style: ThemeMode.light,
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
    merchantDisplayName: 'Kleen My Car',
  ),
);
setState(() {});
displayPaymentSheet();
}



Future<void> displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
          parameters: PresentPaymentSheetParameters(
              clientSecret: paymentIntentData['paymentIntent'],
              confirmPayment: true));
      setState(() {
        paymentIntentData = null;
      });
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Payment succeeded')));
    } catch (e) {
      print('error error error');
    }
  }
```

and here is my index.js file's code

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.testkey);

exports.stripePayment = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
    {
      amount: 120,
      currency: "USD",
    },
    function (err, paymentIntent) {
      if (err != null) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.json({
          paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in index.js file change

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
{
  amount: 120,
  currency: "USD",
},
```

to

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
{
  amount: req.query.amount,
  currency: req.query.currency,
},
```

and deploy your function.
after that, in makepayment function, change your URL to

```
https://us-central1-carwashapp-376b6.cloudfunctions.net/stripePayment?amount=$amount&currency=$currency.
```

In this way, you can pass different amounts every time by changing the value of `$amount` variable in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adapt this line:

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
```

(Firstly, it makes no sense to give a content type on a GET, as GETs don't have any content. Remove that header.)

You could change to a POST and add the amount as a parameter, or leave it as a GET and add the amount to the URL.

With a POST, add (for example) `body: {'amount': amount.toString()}`

With a GET, add it to the URL, as follows:

```
final uri = Uri.https('us-central1-carwashapp-376b6.cloudfunctions.net', '/stripepayment', {'amount': amount.toString()});
```

In your cloud function access `amount` from the `req`. (For example, in the GET example, it would be `req.query.amount as string`.)

We also pass up other parameters like email, unique order id (to be used as the idempotency key), etc.

Comment: To beign with, Thank you soo much for responding.
In addition, all that changes are require in makePayment function. What about code in index.js in which amount is fixed?

Comment: That would be `req.query.amount`. (The amount parameter from the query string of the request.)